# ia32-libs won't install on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: package-management, 64-bit, deb, 15.10

I need the ia32-libs packages because Petalinux SDK requires it.

I have just updated to Ubuntu 15.10 today, and now it won't let me install this package.
I've installed it before on Ubuntu 15.04, so there should be no reason why it won't install on 15.10, right?

I've added the correct file to the sources.list.d directory.

```
    ┌─[♨ steven ♨ ][~] 
    └─(20:38)(pts/2) Prometheus ─╼ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ia32-libs-raring.list
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse
```

I did an update and tried to install the package, but this is all that happens...

```
    ┌─[♨ steven ♨ ][~] 
    └─(20:41)(pts/2) Prometheus ─╼ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
    ┌─[♨ steven ♨ ][~] 
    └─:( (20:42)(pts/2) Prometheus ─╼ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 : Depends: bluez-alsa:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

However when I try to install the `bluez-alsa:i386` package, it tells me it needs `bluez:i386`. When I try to install that one, it tells me I need `bluez-alsa:i386` ... if I try to install both, it tells me they conflict with each other...

Is something broken that I am not seeing? Is support for this `ia32-lib` package completely gone?

Do I just need to downgrade back to 15.04?

I am running 15.10 64-bit

Comment: `ia32-libs` was deprecated and is no longer supported, in favor of multiarch.  You cannot use `ia32-libs` anymore.  That is incompatible with multiarch, and actually isn't needed anymore as a result of multiarch support.

Comment: It is a non-duplicate as Petalinux SDK will NOT work with anything but `ia32-lib`.
So basically, I do need to downgrade?

Comment: or Petalinux SDK needs to upgrade their packaging and take advantage of multiarch.  You either need to use an older release (but I think that's not an option in recent releases instead), or tell Petalinux SDK developers they're on ancient outdated tech/dependencies and need to update their packaging.

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, getting Xilinx to update anything would basically be a true miracle.

Comment: Your other option is to just not use that software... so it's a lose-lose-lose situation all around.

Comment: Petalinux SDK is the only software that can reliably build a Linux kernel for ARM based FPGA's, unfortunately.

Comment: As I said, lose-lose-lose situation all around.